# Filtro com 2 condições ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Boa tarde pessoal, tenho um filtro em ajax que filtra 1 resultado apenas. Preciso filtrar duas condições, tipo mês e nome de uma pessoa numa tabela de agenda. Como posso fazer?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#show_pessoa'),('#mes-agenda').change(function () {
        var chars = (this.value);
        var chars2 = (this.value);
        $.post('../Ajax/pessoa_agenda', {val: chars, val2: chars2}, function (busca) {
            $('#content-left').html(busca);
        });
    });
</script>

        $char = $_POST['val'];
        $char2 = $_POST['val2'];
        $dados = connection::select("Select * from agenda where pessoa= '" . $char . "' and mes = '" . $char2 . "'");
```

Comment: Coloca um botão pra verificar nome ou algo do tipo, quando a pessoa clica, já carrega os 2 valores de uma vez, porque desse jeito ai não vai funcionar. Se a pessoa digita só no campo nome e o campo mês estiver vazio vai somente o valor do campo nome e o resultado da query pode ser o não esperado.

Comment: Pelo que entendi você quer retornar o mês e o nome de uma pessoa na tabela agenda, correto? Minha sugestão você pode fazer um select e retornar um Json.

Comment: Retornar todos os dados, mas filtrando mês e nome junto. Isso via ajax.

Comment: Romario, pensei nisso também. Fica bem mais fácil mesmo. Mas vou tentar fazer por Ajax.

Comment: O que seria esse filtro? Se você vai filtrar após trazer todos os dados do banco, não tem sentido não fazer esse filtro na query. Porque você traz tudo pra não usar tudo dai...